# Best way to trigger an async request after a state update in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
export function useFetch < T > (
  url: string,
  useFullUrl ? : boolean,
  forceReload ? : any,
  method ? : string,
): AsyncState < T > {
  const openModal = useContext(ModalDispatchContext);

  return useAsync({
    promiseFn: useCallback(() => {
      return doFetch(url, {
          method
        }, undefined, useFullUrl, openModal)
        .then(unionToException)
        .then(r => parseResponse < T > (r));
    }, [url, useFullUrl, forceReload, method, openModal]),
  });
}
```

This function should trigger an async request, handle the response, and open a modal if necessary. In some cases, the request should be retriggered if an external state changes as a result of user interactions or another request. Therefore, I added `forceReload` to control this.

The function works fine but the linter shows me this:

> React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'forceReload'.
> Either exclude it or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Of course, I can disable it but I would be curious to understand what would be the proper way to obtain the same behavior and a happy linter.

Comment: why don't you try `useEffect`?

Comment: Why are you adding forceReload to the dependency array of useCallback? It's not using it.

Comment: @Sword I I tried that too but the warning is the same. Also, useAsync allows me to get a promise and show a loading bar

Comment: @hellogoodnight  forceReload is actually used to retrigger the new call from the component that calls useFetch. But I indeed wonder what would be a better way.